# JavaFX angled TableView Headers

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Is there a way to angle column headers on an JavaFX TableView? Excel has a function like this when you have a ton of columns. Basically my column count has exceeded my optimal amount (lol) and I'd LIKE to have angled headers. Here is what I'm talking about.

[image]

I realize (with a hack of sorts) you can have headers with vertical text but my OM asked if I can make them angled. I'd really like to not have to create my own TableView class with all custom containers to accomplish this.

Comment: nothing out of the box, but basically, you'll need a custom TableHeaderRow (that's the parent container for the header), custom NestedTableColumnHeader (that's the "real" one-level container for the column headers, which does the layout - if I remember correctly) and a custom TableColumnHeader (that's the per-column header that contains the label/titel/sort-icon) . Hmm ... quite a task but could be interesting ..

Comment: Yeah it's something that could be a bit fun but I'm not sure I want to waste the hours at work trying to make this. I gave my manager a vertical column sheet with Labels rotated -90 and that works pretty good so we might just have to go with that. I just don't have the time to do this but if someone wants to give it a go........ lolol

Comment: I had the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164114/is-it-possible-to-make-diagonal-column-headers-in-javafx).

Comment: Maybe I should create my own library for this lol.