# Is it possible to make diagonal column headers in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, rotation, custom-controls

My JavaFX TableView looks something like this:

[image]

It would be so much more pleasing and efficient if the labels at the top were *diagonal* to save space.

I imagine it like so:

[image]

The goal is to make the column fit closely to the content despite a long header label.

Can it be done?

Comment: This was asked a while ago, though I can't find it now. I think the consensus was that you would need to write a new `TableViewSkin` (and the user who posted the original question figured it wasn't worth the effort). It would, at a minimum, be a bit of a project...

Comment: I looked for a similar question, but didn't find anything either.

Comment: [Found a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566684/javafx-angled-tableview-headers), with no answer.

Comment: That was the one I was thinking of.